# API to get Frequently asked questions of a search

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, bing-api

I'm trying to find if I can get the "People also asked" of a search in an API in the Google Cloud Platform or in an other Search Engine API.

For example, when you make a search in Google, there is a section called "People also asked". I try to find an API to get the informations in this section. I want the questions an the answers.

[image]

I didn't found anything but I'm quite sure it exists.

Can you help me founding it?

Comment: Can you describe your search? When you search what? and where?

Comment: For example when I search a plant "Dracaena fragrans" in Google there is a section called "People also asked". I want an API to get these questions and answers.

Comment: I think I understand your question, but I am not sure. Maybe adding a screenshot could make a difference?

Comment: Or actually it's about some Google Cloud Platform.. Not sure.. Can you show an example of an API that you are using, and refer to the API spec page please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a regular google search at like https://www.google.com/search?q=Dracaena%20fragrans ? Is it an autocomplete API that you are looking for?

If I open a network monitor on that page (google chrome browser has it), then I am able to find some requests that look something like what you are probably looking for(see the picture below).

[image: network monitor in chrome]

Having that said I see this API being used:

https://www.google.com/complete/search?q=Dracaena%20fragrans%20&cp=18&client=psy-ab&xssi=t&gs_ri=gws-wiz&hl=en-UA&authuser=0&psi=gpjbX9nAL5K7UNGAmMAK.1608226950136&dpr=1

Not sure where to be looking for API specs though.
[Here maybe](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)?

Comment: Thans for the answer igrek. I've updated my post with some screenshots.